# How can I move out of a loop when no swaps happen in bubble sort?

Tags: c++

This code is about bubble sort and it runs n times. Any time when array values are not swapped, I want control to move out of the loop.

How can I do that?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size=4;
    int arr[size];
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size-1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                temp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<i<<"]: "<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but things like indentation is kind of important to make code readable. If the code is not readable then it's harder to understand what it does, and fewer people will be willing to try and help you.

Comment: Have a look to break and continue

Comment: set some flag to true insde of the `if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]){...}` and then check for that flag after the inner for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want to exit the outer loop whenever the inner loop doesn't make any changes.

So,

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    bool done = true;
    for(j=0;j<size-1;j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
        {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
            done = false;
        }
    }
    if (done)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you should use some flag in the inner loop to indicate that the vector is sorted. You could check the flag and break out of the outer-loop if no swap has been made. However, it is easier to use the flag as an ending condition for the outer-loop. An implementation, with bit more modern c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v={1,4,1,5,7,3,2,3,10};
  bool sorted = false;
  while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < v.size(); ++i){
      if (v[i] > v[i+1]){
        std::swap(v[i], v[i+1]);
        sorted = false;
      }
    }
  } 
  for (auto i : v){
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```